# How to create a simple Modal Dialog Box in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, overlay, modal-dialog

I'm trying to build up a simple JQuery function : A modal box
(one of my first, we all start somewhere ;)

So I use an overlay but my box is covered by the overlay, how could I make this box appear opaque at 100% when the whole page is covered by a white overlay?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="overlay">
    <h4 style='text-align:left;'>Confirmation</h4>
    <p style='margin-top:5%;margin-bottom:15%;'>Es-Tu satisfait de la couverture du Magazine ?</p>
    <input value="Non, Corriger" id="close" class="submitMagHalf" />
    <input type="submit" value="Oui,envoyer" class='submitMagHalf'/>
</div>
<div id='boxConf'>
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#overlay{
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    text-align: center;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:white;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-100px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-200px;
    border:1px;
    border-bottom:10px #082545;
}

#boxConf{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:200%;
    background-color:white;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
      $(".submitMag").click(function() {
         $("#overlay").show();
         $("#overlay").fadeTo(1000,1.0);
         $("#boxConf:not(#overlay)").fadeTo(2000,0.5);

      });

      $("#close").click(function() {
         $("#overlay").hide();
         $("body:not(#overlay)").fadeTo('fast',2.0);

      });

      $("#overlay").hide();
      $("#boxConf").hide();
 });
```

Comment: OKAY ! Z-index was the answer ! z-index(#boxeConf)>z-inex(#overlay)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read up on how css z-index works to determine which layers are on top of which. Higher the z-index, higher the priority